# Keras Preprocessing Rotates Image While Importing It With load_img()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I just started learning the Keras API and I am experimenting with the MNIST dataset. I got it working correctly but I have a problem with the function `load_img()` `from the keras.preprocessing.image` library, when I try to test a picture that I took. It imports a portrait oriented image as a landscape one. I took the photo with my smartphone in portrait mode and Windows correctly shows width 3024 and height 4032 pixels.

When I load that image and print the width and height it shows 4032x3024. Also when I do `img.show()`, it seems to have been rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. All that is happening right after loading it, without any processing. I tried looking into the API for the `load_img()` and couldn't find any arguments that make it rotate while loading.

This is a dummy example to show you the problem:

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img

img = load_img('filepath/test.jpg') # Load portrait mode image Windows says 3024x4032
width, height = img.size
print(width, height) # Prints 4032 3024
img.show() # Shows it rotated by 90 degrees counterclockwise
```

I want it to be imported in portrait mode. Why does it get rotated? The problem is that a picture taken in landscape mode is also imported as 4032 x 3024, so I can't differentiate between the 2 orientations. I want to be able to rotate the image if it's in portrait mode but not rotate it if it's in landscape mode.

EDIT: I just tried to load the image with Pillow and the results are exactly the same

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
jhead -v YourImage.jpg
```

to check the EXIF parameter called `Orientation` - phone cameras set it so that images can be rotated. Try it for one image that works and another image that is *"unhappy"*.

You can correct it with **ImageMagick**:

```
convert unhappy.jpg -auto-orient happy.jpg
```

Or maybe more easily with `exiftool`. Discussion and example [here](https://leancrew.com/all-this/2009/04/derotating-jpegs-with-exiftool/).

Comment: I am not familiar with Keras, but maybe its `img_load()` can divulge the EXIF data to you even more simply.

Comment: You can get the EXIF info in PIL/Pillow like this `img.info['exif']`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will try them out now. I tried something which worked. I opened the image (jpg) with paint, did absolutely nothing to it and saved it again as jpg. This time it has the correct orientation inside keras and pillow. I don't understand how windows shows me width 3024 and height 4032 pixels for both the raw smartphone pic and the one that has been through paint. Python treats those 2 pictures differently.

P.S. My phone is a Xiaomi Pocophone F1

Comment: Did you try running `jhead` or `exiftool` like I suggested?

Comment: Yes I tried exif. I get some really weird data as shown in the comment below when I run print(img.info['exif'])

Comment: b'Exif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x0c\x01\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x0f\xc0\x00\x00\x01\x10\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x9e\x01\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x0b\xd0\x00\x00\x01\x12\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06\x00\x00\x012

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by saving image from keras again.

```
from tensorflow import keras

path = "file_path"
img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img( path ) 
img = ndimage.rotate( img , 270 ) #rotate 270 degree
keras.preprocessing.image.save_img( path , img )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).